# How do I periodically execute a runnable class from a main method?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class `Clock`, the code for which is below. I want to execute the run method found in Clock every x amount of seconds. But I want this to be initiated from a Main method, not from the Clock class itself.

To put it simply, Clock will be used to simulate a clock unit found in a CPU. Every x amount of seconds, the state of the Clock class will change between a `1` and a `0`, causing the state of the rest of the program to change. The Main method of the program will create a Clock object and this will execute periodically in the background until the program is terminated.

I've read about the `ScheduledExecutorService` and I thought this would be ideal, however this can only be used to execute a single runnable object, not an entire runnable class.

Is there anyway to execute my Clock class every x amount of seconds from a Main method located in a separate class?

Clock class

```
public class Clock implements Runnable{

    private int state = 0; //the state of the simulation, instrutions will execute on the rising edge;
    private float executionSpeed; //in Hz (executions per second)

    private String threadName = "Clock";

    public Clock(float exeSpeed)
    {
        executionSpeed = exeSpeed;
        System.out.println("[Clock] Execution speed set to " + executionSpeed + "Hz. (" + (1/executionSpeed) + " instructions per second.)");
    }

    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println(threadName + " executed.");
        toggleState();
    }

    public void toggleState()
    {
        if(state == 1)
        {
            state = 0;
        }
        else if(state == 0)
        {
            state = 1;
        }
    }

    public float getExecutionSpeed()
    {
        return executionSpeed;
    }

}
```

I want to periodically execute Clock from here:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        float period = 1.0;
        Clock clockUnit = new Clock(period);

        //execute clock.run() every 1.0 seconds
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you'll find this useful: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#tick-java.time.Clock-java.time.Duration-

Comment: "however this can only be used to execute a single runnable object, not an entire runnable class." - This statement makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at java.util.Timer? This will allow you to exectute a TimerTask periodically.

You will need to change your class Clock to extend TimerTask.

```
float period = 1.0f;
Clock clockUnit = new Clock(period);
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(clockUnit, 0, 1000);
```